# Powershell array ignorance

Tags: arrays, powershell, count

'scuse my ignorance...
I use `@($var).Count` so I can get a count even if `$var` contains 1 "item".
When my search returns nothing why does my array contain one item?
i.e.

```
  PS C:\Windows\system32> $Groups = $null

    Import-Module -Name "activedirectory"

    $search = "aaaarggg"

    $searchPat = `"*"` + $search + `"*"`

    $Groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter {(name -like $searchPat)}

    if ($Groups -eq $null) {
        "No matches"
        @($Groups).Count
    }
    else {
        "Matches"
        @($Groups).Count
    }



 No matches

    1
```

Comment: Because you are creating an array with a single element - null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Lee said you create array which contains one item and the item is null. It may seem illogical, but it is done this way to give you consistent results when decrementing or incrementing the amount of items in the array. Look at the example below. If the `@($null).count` returned `0` you would jump from `2` to `0`.

```
@($null,$null,$null).Count #output 3
@($null,$null).Count #output 2
@($null).Count #output 1
@().Count #output 0
```

Ingoring `$null` values inside the `@()` operator would also render such situations impossible to handle:

```
$("a",$null,"c").count #output 3
$("a","b","c").count #output 3
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Powershell doc](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692797.aspx)
You create an empty array as `$a = @()`

To count the elements you can simply do 
`$a.Count`

```
$x = @()
$x.Count
0
```

As for processing the results of `Get-ADGroup`, that depends on what it returns. I think you'll find that simply doing
    if ($Groups.Count -eq 0 ) {
     # process
    }
will work for you.